# Intermittent issue connecting to WampServer website from mobile device

Tags: apache, google-chrome, mobile, wampserver

I have a website setup on a wampserver (2.4) and when I am trying to use a mobile device (Android/Chrome) to view the site I get 'Oops! Google Chrome could not [find the site].'

This isn't always the case and I am sometimes able to view the website just fine. Once connected it seems fine, i.e. I can traverse all of the site and it does not disconnect whilst in use.

I have tried everything I can think of:

1. httpd.conf: I've made the change to Require local, Require ip 192.168.2 (I've double/triple checked the IP address);
2. Firewall (windows and webroot): when I am unable to access the site, I have disabled both of the firewalls. I have also added port 80 to the windows firewall inbound rules exceptions list.
3. restarted the wampserver multiple times, but to no avail.

httpd.conf:

```
#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
# onlineoffline tag - do not remove
Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
Require local    
Require ip 192.168.2
```

The website is always accessible on the development machine.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Many thanks,
Arwy

Comment: How are you connecting to the server? You should provide the code in your question.

Comment: You'll have better luck asking on a different site -- SO is for programming questions, yours seems to be related to configuration or networking.

Comment: I was just entering the website address in Chrome, 192.168.2.103/webpage.php. Yeh, I think it probably is the configuration of Apache or something. Will try another forum. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, just incase someone else sees this post, this is what helped me:  http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,121517

I added these two lines : 'AcceptFilter http none' and 'AcceptFilter https none'

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue. That is solved by adding these lines

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

in the httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Arvy,

I think you already know this but for the benefit of others with this problem

Try this:

Add these two lines anywhere in your httpd.conf ( not inside another section ), then restart your Apache server:

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

Comment: Hey, thought I'd mention that upon restarting the wifi connection on my laptop (which hosts the development server) that I am able to access the site on the mobile device. Therefore, I assume there is something going wrong with the router. Anyways, I appreciate the help RiggsFolly. Hopefully anyone else having issues can resolve them by trying to reset the wifi.